# Club two queries using Joins

Tags: php, mysql, join

Lets assume i have two queries shown as below

```
select a.item1,b.item2 from tablename a,tablename b;

store a.item1 as $value1;

select c.item3 from tablename c where c.item4=$value1;
```

I need these two queries club together into a single query and also using `Joins`.

```
P.S: in PHP.
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having identical fields in three tables,you can do so by the following query,

```
select a.item1 as value1,b.item2,c.item3 from tablename a inner join tablename b on a.id=b.table1_id inner join tablename c on c.item4=value1;
```

Regards,
Rekha

Answer (score 0):

If your table names is 'a', 'b' and 'c' then you can join them this way:

```
SELECT a.item1, b.item2, c.item3 FROM a, b
  INNER JOIN c ON a.item1 = c.item4;
```

No need PHP code, only SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
select a.item1,b.item2,c.item3 from a join b on a.id = b.table_a.id
join c on a.item1 = c.item4
```